# What does entanglement cause between particles?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement

I've heard a lot of what **quantum entanglement isn't** such as it not being able to transfer information especially not faster than the speed of light.

At this point, **I want to know what it can do**. Why is it so cool and interesting? What is its use in quantum computers? Does the first particle impact the second at all other than spin probabilities? What are all the possibilities of entanglement for the future? Finally, is the spin the only thing that is connected between the particles?

**I am not asking for a lesson on entanglement from the basics**. I have watched a lot of those. I am asking in summary what is so cool, what are its uses, is there anything other than quantum spin, and what about the wave function?

Thank you so much!

Comment: It's cool and interesting because it breaks our understanding of the fundamental principles of physics -- per Bell's theorem and the EPR paradox, no valid interpretation of QM can satisfy all of: causality, locality, realism, and determinism.  Those are all pretty fundamental properties that it intuitively seems like all theories ought to have, and yet, the math of entanglement means we can't have all four of them (at least, not unless you buy into super-determinism, which, frankly, is far too implausible to be taken seriously, IMO).